# Register-ScheduledJob and Write-Host

Tags: job-scheduling, powershell-3.0

I'm using [Register-ScheduledJob](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850536.aspx) to register job in powershell in background job I execute script. This script contains some commands like Get-Process and Write-Host command. And...

Altough every command is executed in results I don't see outputs from write-hosts (get-Process is is ok)

Maybe someone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write-Host writes to the host, which is the app that the script is running in (PowerShell.exe for instance), so it is output explicitly to the screen, and DOES NOTHING when you're running in a non-interactive environment.  You should never use that to output data that you want to collect, only for lightweight debugging or for printing to the screen in interactive scripts.

You should generally use write-output for the data that you want to collect as output.

Although you can also use the debug/warning/error output (those are collected by the job, but not shown in the regular output).

Answer (score 0):

Thank You very much. Write-Output helped.

Additionaly what i discover during last days and could be helpful for others: if you start scheduled background job and in this job start powershell script like this:

```
Register-ScheduledJob -Name1 temp -ScheduledJobOption $option -ScriptBlock {
D:\scprit.ps1
}
```

Your job will never end because after finish script powershell window is still open. So additionaly you have to add exit in your scriptblock:

```
Register-ScheduledJob -Name1 temp -ScheduledJobOption $option -ScriptBlock {
D:\scprit.ps1
Exit-PSSession
}
```